# Python REGEX and File I/O

Tags: python, regex

Still Learning python and very new to REGEX.  I am trying to get information from a text file and put it into a list for later processing:

Here is a sample python file:

```
import re

text = '''name = file details
version = v1.2
;----------------
; Notes on line one
; Notes on line two
;
; Notes on line four, skipping line 3
;--------------
configuring this device
configuring that device
; I don't want this note'''



def notes(path):
    file = re.split('\n+', path)
    outputName = outputVer = outputNote = ''
    notes = []
    outputNotes = []
    for line in file:
        name = re.search('^name = (.*)$', line)
        ver = re.search('^version = (.*)$', line)
        note = re.search('; (.*)', line)
        if name:
            outputName = name.group(1)
        if ver:
            outputVer  = ver.group(1)
        notes.append(note)
    for note in notes:
        print(note)



    info = (outputName, outputVer, outputNotes)
    print(info[2])

    for notes in info[2]:
        if notes:
            print(notes)

    print(info)


notes(text)
```

What I want is to grab the "name", "version" and "notes"

I can get the name and version with no issues, the notes is what I'm having a problem with.  For the notes I want everything in between the ;--------- marks.  I do not want the notes that are later in the file.

essentially, I want the output to look like:

```
('file details', 'v1.2', ['Notes on line one', 'Notes on line two', '','Notes on line four, skipping line 3'])
```

Also, I'm sure there are ways to optimize this, I'd be interested to hear suggestions.

Comment: Please post content of the file and post what you want to extract explicitely and clearly.

Comment: I included sample content from a file in the "text" variable included in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem statement, you are just reading a varying number of lines at the top of the file. There is no reason to use a regex for this at all - just read 2 lines for name and version, then read the header start line (';---') then loop, reading lines into an array, until you see the header end line (';---').

Answer (score 0):

With [MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) and [DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) mode:

```
(?:^;-+$)(.*?)(?:^;-+$)
```

See a [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eY0kH2/1)
Or here as a complete walkthrough:

```
import re

text = _your_string_

def notes():
    lines = re.split('\n', text)
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('name'):
            name = re.search(r"^name = (.*)", line)
            if (name):
                outputName = name.group(1)
        elif line.startswith('version'):
            version = re.search(r"^version = (.*)", line)
            if (version):
                outputVer = version.group(1)

    # now the notes part
    notes = re.search(r"(?:^;-+$)(.*?)(?:^;-+$)", text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    outputNotes = [x.strip() for x in re.split(r'\n;?', notes.group(1)) if x]
    info = [outputName, outputVer, outputNotes]
    return info

info = notes()
print info
# ['file details', 'v1.2', ['Notes on line one', 'Notes on line two', 'Notes on line four, skipping line 3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs mix of multiple approach as below- I used `named-capture-group`, to extract `notes` i applied regex twice firstly to select text inside `;-----` and the the line have text inside them not merely `;`.

```
import re

txt = '''name = file details
version = v1.2
;----------------
; Notes on line one
; Notes on line two
;
; Notes on line four, skipping line 3
;--------------
configuring this device
configuring that device
; I don't want this note'''
data = re.search(r'name\s*=\s*(?P<name>.*)\W*version\s*=\s*(?P<version>.*)\W*(?:;-+\W)(?P<notes>[\w\W]*)(?:;-+\W)',txt)
print data.group('name')#prints name
print data.group('version')#prints version
#print data.group('notes')
print [i.strip(';') for i in re.findall(r';\s*[^;]{2,}',data.group('notes'))]#prints notes
```

Output-

```
file details
v1.2
[' Notes on line one\n', ' Notes on line two\n', ' Notes on line four, skipping line 3\n']
```

See Details of the first regex at <kbd>[HERE](https://regex101.com/r/eY0kH2/2)</kbd>